# Twist_controller speedl function error on robot teachpendant

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm currently working on a teleoperation project with an UR robot and I'm trying to use the `twist_controller` from the `ur_robot_driver` to control the robot.
But I keep running intro an error whenever I try to run a command such as:

```
danielh@danielh:~/catkin_ws$ rostopic pub /twist_controller/command geometry_msgs/Twist "linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.01
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0"
```

The error is as such:

```
The robot cannot reach the requested pose. Script function speedl is unable to find an inverse kinematics solution.
```

The real robot is in a pose similar to this one:

[image: image description]

How is the function `speedl` related to this problem and what fix is there for this?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386104/twist_controller-speedl-function-error-on-robot-teachpendant/) by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-09**:
A twist is a linear and angular velocity in a (in this case) Cartesian space.

What is the pose of your robot when you start using the twist controller?

If it's already at or near a maximum I could imagine it can't move linearly in the Y+ direction any more.

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-09-09**:
It's in a vertical pose, exactly as the one in the image from [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/385928/big-difference-between-simulated-robot-and-real-robot-ros_control-position-velocity-controllers/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please add that image to this post.

re: your error: that's not going to work.

You're asking the robot to go in a straight line in a direction in which it cannot move any more (due to the pose it's currently in).

Put it in a more neutral pose, with its elbow bent, so the lower arm is parallel to the ground plane.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-09-10**:
Alright, so indeed the problem was with the robot's pose. I moved it into a neutral pose and now it works. Thanks for the help!